# php in html, some part of code is not displaying

Tags: php, html

I would like to learn PHP and started reading this info's in the website: And I have question about this code:

Why is this line not displaying? " echo 'Neo: I am Neo, but my people call me The One.';"

Thanks

```
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  Agent: So who do you think you are, anyhow?
  <br />

  <?php
  // print output
  echo 'Neo: I am Neo, but my people call me The One.';
  ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: please specify your OS? server activated (i mean running) ?

Comment: @Nagaraj:i'm using win 7 xampp

Comment: Do you see the php code when you view the source of the web page from your browser?

Comment: @erisco:what do u mean?i save this as html & then I run it in firefox.how can I do that?

Comment: When viewing the web page, hit ctrl+U or cmd+U on a Mac. Alternatively you may right-click somewhere on the web page and select `View Page Source` in the context menu. If you see the PHP code, it means PHP is not correctly configured with your server - or you made a mistake such as giving the file a `.html` extension instead of `.php`.

Comment: @erisco:yes when i view the page source, the php code is italicize. that's my next problem now, how can i start php using my xampp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a webserver, and give it a .php extension.
You cannot run it directly from your drive (e.g. /home/user/file.php or C:\file.php), you must run it from your server (e.g. http://localhost/file.php or http://example.com/file.php)

A webserver can be downloaded from http://www.xampp.org/

Comment: as i'm a beginner forgive me for my question, can i use xampp as my server?

Comment: ok cool I have it already, i would like to know how to use it?

Comment: If you've installed XAMPP in C:\xampp, put your files in `C:\xampp\htdocs`. Example: `C:\xampp\htdocs\file.php` is accessible with `http://localhost/file.php`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using a virtual webserver such as mamp or xampp,
Also try print instead of echo with "

Comment: i'm using xampp, what does it mean virtual webserver? i would like to know how to use this with my xampp, using windows 7

Comment: That's not a *virtual* webserver, but a webserver. Using `print` instead of `echo` won't solve the problem.